# Where is the sudo group or is it replaced by group wheel

Tags: permission, file, high-sierra, sudo

On the Mac, there is no sudo group. But inside the sudoers file, there is something called the wheel and it says:

> root and user in group wheel can run anything on any machine as any user.

And it has `%admin ALL = (ALL) ALL` below it. Does group wheel take the place of the sudo group? If not, where is the sudo group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group `admin` is synonymous with the group `sudo` found on Linux boxes. Members of the group `wheel` have a special privilege where they can `su` (switch user) to `root` assuming that the member knows `root`'s password. Since the `root` account is disabled, membership in the group `wheel` would be similar to membership in the group `admin`, if configured in `/private/etc/sudoers`. Since some Apple supplied command line tools require `admin` membership, the group `wheel` is a vestige from FreeBSD.

Comment: My account is neither in the wheel group or the admin group and I am still able to use sudo. Why is that?